# Convert rows to columns in PowerQuery. Transpose & Pivot methods not giving correct results

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a PowerQuery table called "On Holds" in Excel as below:

```
| Action User | Index |
|-------------|-------|
| Employee A  | 1     |
| Employee B  | 1     |
| Employee B  | 1     |
| Employee B  | 1     |
| Employee C  | 1     |
| Employee C  | 1     |
| Employee C  | 1     |
| Employee C  | 1     |
| Employee C  | 1     |
| Employee D  | 1     |
| Employee D  | 1     |
| Employee D  | 1     |
```

**I'm looking to convert it to look like this (it'll have column headers, but I'm not bothered what they are):**

```
| ﻿Employee A | 1 |   |   |   |   |
| Employee B | 1 | 1 | 1 |   |   |
| Employee C | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| Employee D | 1 | 1 | 1 |   |   |
```

I have a separate table (*TeamMembers*) that lists unique employee names that I've tried joining to create this list but ultimately end up with versions similar to the original table.

I could do it with VBA or a series of Transpose formula outside of Powerquery but feel this isn't the best way to go - formula would need updating each week to take into account the different number of rows.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

A basic transpose doesn't work as it ends up like this:

```
| Column1    | Column2    | Column3    | Column4    | Column5    | Column6    |
|------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|
| Employee A | Employee B | Employee B | Employee B | Employee C | Employee C |
| 1          | 1          | 1          | 1          | 1          | 1          |
```

A pivot ends up like this:

```
| Employee A | Employee B | Employee C | Employee D |
|------------|------------|------------|------------|
| 1          | 3          | 5          | 3          |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The overall trick is to get a new column with cumulative count on Action User into the table:

Select Action User column.  Group By ... [x] Basic, Group by:Action User, New column Name:Count, Operation:Count Rows [ok]

and modify resulting code from

```
= Table.Group(Source, {"Action User"}, {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), type number}})
```

to

```
= Table.Group(Source, {"Action User"}, {{"Count", each Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Cum",1,1), type table}})
```

Expand Index and Cum by clicking on arrows next to Count column header

Select Cum column, Pivot column.., using Index as Values Column [x] advanced options, don't aggregate

Full code below

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Action User"}, {{"Count", each Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Cum",1,1), type table}}),
#"Expanded Count" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Count", {"Index", "Cum"}, {"Index", "Cum"}),
#"Pivoted Column1" = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Count", {{"Cum", type text}}, "en-US"), List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Count", {{"Cum", type text}}, "en-US")[Cum]), "Cum", "Index")
in #"Pivoted Column1"
```

Comment: Quick question - if the `Index` column are various numbers in ascending order so, for example, _Employee B_ has numbers 7, 443 & 913 why does the number not stay in numerical order?  It comes out as 443, 7, 913 which seems to be a text sort and the column type shows ABC123 rather than just 123.  Is there something I could add to keep those in numerical order?

Comment: Mine shows up as original sort, so don't know why. Try Alexis' below maybe

Comment: Apologies - it shows in the correct order if I remember to sort it first.  The column I didn't show in my example is "Cumm. Days on Hold" and `#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Filtered Rows",{{"Action User", Order.Ascending}, {"Cumm. Days on Hold", Order.Ascending}}),` brought everything out correctly.  Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to do a Group By and change your aggregating function. To concatenate instead of sum/max/average. Then you can split by the delimiter you use in your concatenating `Text.Combine` function.

When you do a Group By, the step usually looks like this:

```
= Table.Group(Source, {"ActionUser"}, {{"Sum", each List.Sum([Index]), type number}})
```

What I've done is replace `List.Sum([Index])` by the following:

```
Text.Combine(List.Transform([Index], Text.From), ",")
```

This converts the numbers to text and then concatenates them with `Text.Combine` using a comma as the delimiter to give a table like this:

[image: Group By Concatenated]

From here, Transform > Split Column > By Delimiter will complete the job.

---

Full M code:

```
let
    Source = Table1,
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"ActionUser"}, {{"Concat", each Text.Combine(List.Transform([Index], Text.From), ","), type text}}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Concat", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Concat.1", "Concat.2", "Concat.3", "Concat.4", "Concat.5"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Concat.1", Int64.Type}, {"Concat.2", Int64.Type}, {"Concat.3", Int64.Type}, {"Concat.4", Int64.Type}, {"Concat.5", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @Alexis.  Problem I'm having with this answer is that it only shows five columns worth of data (as that's what my example had).  My actual data has a variable number of columns - at the moment the minimum is 1 column and the maximum is 28 columns.

Comment: Yeah. It's possible to make this more dynamic for variable columns but horseyride's solution is probably better in that case.

Answer (score 0):

As variant

```
let
   Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
   #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Action User", type text}, {"Index", type text}}),
   #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Action User"}, {{"Count", each _[Index]}}),
   Custom1 = Table.FromColumns(#"Grouped Rows"[Count],#"Grouped Rows"[Action User]),
   #"Demoted Headers" = Table.DemoteHeaders(Custom1),
   #"Transposed Table" = Table.Transpose(#"Demoted Headers")
in
   #"Transposed Table"
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.